# How to select the title that has the highest value?

Tags: mysql, sql

So in a simple table like this one, how could I select the title which has the highest value?

```
|_title_||_value_|
|_title1_||_50652_|
|_title2_||_57465_|
|_title3_||_68565_|
|_title4_||_14645_|
```

Like in this case title3 has the highest value, so I'd like to select title3 with a SQL code, but I don't know how to

What I've tried:

```
SELECT title FROM table HAVING MAX(value);
```

I thought this is how I can do it, but it doesn't work. I'm completely new to SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subquery if you want to allow for multiple titles sharing the same maximum value:

```
select title from table where value = (select max(value) from table);
```

---

EDIT: As to your own query:

You aggregate all rows to a single one by asking for the `MAX(value)` without a `GROUP BY` clause. But then you select `title`. Which? You don't tell the DBMS and so the query is actually invalid SQL. MySQL, however, lets this slip and silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on `title`, which is not what you want. You want a particular one.

There is another flaw in your query: In `HAVING MAX(value)` you have no comparison (like in `HAVING MAX(value) > 1000` for instance). But the DBMS expects an expression with a boolean result (true or false or null). Your expression should ideally raise an error, but MySQL simply converts the value to boolean with false = 0, true <> 0. 68565 is not zero, so the condition is true.

So you end up with a single row holding an arbitrarily picked title.

Comment: Great explanation. The only person to explain why OP's SQL wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 5):

use `limit` and order by using value in descending order

```
select * from table
order by value desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `order by` clause with `limit` clause :

```
SELECT title
FROM table
ORDER BY val DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return only 1 row, if you have same higher value then you will need to use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.val = (select max(t1.val) from table t1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If using MySQL 8+ or later, we can use analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT title, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT title, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The potential advantage of this approach is that if we want to also find all possible ties for first place, should they occur, we need only substitute `ROW_NUMBER` for `RANK` (or maybe `DENSE_RANK`), and we can get all ties for first.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT title 
FROM t1
order by value desc
limit 1;
```